# Map Mono<Resources<Resource<T>>> to Mono<List<T>>?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-hateoas

In my reactive Java 9 Spring Boot 2 with Spring HATEOAS application, I have a REST API returning `Mono<Resources<Resource<T>>>`. In the application layer, I'd like the data to be `Mono<List<T>>` but how can I concisely map `Mono<Resources<Resource<T>>>` to `Mono<List<T>>`?

I was expecting something like:

```
public Mono<List<Order>> orders() {
    return rest.orders()
        .flatmap(List::stream)
        .map(r -> r.getContent())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

but this fails to compile because `List` does not define `List.stream(Resources<Resource<Order>>`. The `rest.orders()` returns `Mono<Resources<Resource<Order>>>`. Any ideas?

Comment: `Mono` doesn't have a `collect` method either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (memory-sloshing) solution:

```
public Mono<List<Order>> orders() {
    return rest.orders()
        .map(r -> toList(r));
}

private List<Order> toList(Resources<Resource<Order>> resources) {
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    resources.forEach(r -> orders.add(r.getContent());
    return orders;
}
```